# Cannot make SQL and PHP work

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

so I'm trying to upload files into my database with SQL. This following code works when I try it in localhost, but not on my actual server.  I tested it's conenction to the database and it connects, but it won't upload.

```
if (isset($_POST['uploadtodb'])) {
$asdupload = 0;
while ($asdupload < 25 && isset($_SESSION{"matchq0-" . $asdupload})) {
$q0upload = $_SESSION{"matchq0-" . $asdupload};
$q1upload = $_SESSION{"matchq1-" . $asdupload};
$q2upload = $_SESSION{"matchq2-" . $asdupload};
$q3upload = $_SESSION{"matchq3-" . $asdupload};
$q4upload = $_SESSION{"matchq4-" . $asdupload};
$q5upload = $_SESSION{"matchq5-" . $asdupload};
$q6upload = $_SESSION{"matchq6-" . $asdupload};
$q7upload = $_SESSION{"matchq7-" . $asdupload};
$q8upload = $_SESSION{"matchq8-" . $asdupload};
$q9upload = $_SESSION{"matchq9-" . $asdupload};
$q10upload = $_SESSION{"matchq10-" . $asdupload};
$q11upload = $_SESSION{"matchq11-" . $asdupload};
$q12upload = $_SESSION{"matchq12-" . $asdupload};
$q13upload = $_SESSION{"matchq13-" . $asdupload};
$q14upload = $_SESSION{"matchq14-" . $asdupload};
$q15upload = $_SESSION{"matchq15-" . $asdupload};
$teamnumupload = $_SESSION['teamnum'];
include 'config.php';
$sqlupload = "INSERT INTO matches(q0, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, teamnum) VALUES('$q0upload', '$q1upload', '$q2upload', '$q3upload', '$q4upload', '$q5upload', '$q6upload', '$q7upload', '$q8upload', '$q9upload', '$q10upload', '$q11upload', '$q12upload', '$q13upload', '$q14upload', '$q15upload', '$teamnumupload')";
if ($db) {
    echo "connected to db";
} else {
echo "not connected to db";
}
if (mysqli_query($db, $sqlupload)) {
echo "<script>Alert.render('Successfully uploaded rows into database.', '')</script>";
unset($_SESSION{"matchq0-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq1-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq2-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq3-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq4-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq5-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq6-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq7-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq8-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq9-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq10-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq11-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq12-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq13-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq14-" . $asdupload});
unset($_SESSION{"matchq15-" . $asdupload});
$_SESSION['matchcapacity'] = 0;
} else {
echo "<script>Alert.render('Unable to upload rows into database. Check your connection, and make sure you are online.', '')</script>";  
}
    $asdupload++;
}

}
```

The reason of me having a variable at the end of the session, is because I have sessions with for example, `$_SESSION['matchq0-0']; $_SESSION['matchq0-1']; $_SESSION['matchq0-2'];` etc.

config.php has the sql connection info

Comment: shouldn't this $_SESSION{"matchq0-" . $asdupload} be $_SESSION["matchq0-" . $asdupload]

Comment: @Satya No, I tried doing that, and it didn't work. I read the php manual and it said what I did should work, and it works both in my localhost and actual server. I printed the sessions. It won't upload in my actual server but it will on my localhost one

Comment: It's time to learn about `for` if you are having to repeat things like this.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

change your curly brace to square bracket `[]`

your session should be like this `$_SESSION["matchq0-" . $asdupload]`

Comment: I did a `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: The sessions are working, because I get this when I did a var dump `["matchq3-0"]=> string(4) "text"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry everyone, but I made a huge mistake, and I had an error in my SQL table name. I appreciate your help. Sorry about that